# Using TTLCache :: cachetools

Tags: python-3.x, caching

I want to use cachetools, when I use below codes in a python file, the cache never expired:

```
from cachetools import TTLCache
cache = TTLCache(maxsize=10, ttl=6)
cache['a'] = "b"
print(cache['a'])
```

But when I use from python console it expires after 6 seconds. I'm confused about this module's logic. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for the TTL to expire before trying to get the key

```
from cachetools import TTLCache
cache = TTLCache(maxsize=10, ttl=6)
cache['a'] = "b"

time.sleep(6.5) # wait for expiry

print(cache['a'])
```

This results in a `KeyError`

Comment: but I want to get cache value in 6 seconds without sleep. This code runs in console perfectly but not via a python file

Comment: The cache keeps the value mapped to `a` for 6 seconds for as long as the python process is running. If you don't do anything after setting the value and retrieving it the cache will give you the value. If you do something after 6 seconds, then the cache will give you an error.